# Full screen Win Form Application not working through Task Scheduler

Tags: .net, windows, windows-task-scheduler

I have created a windows form application that runs a web page in full screen mode. The business wants the user to give input and then the application exits on its own.

The requirement is to run this application on every system unlock. And the dev had no time to code the trigger service inside the application.

So we decided to run the .exe on every system unlock event through traditional task scheduler.

Through task scheduler, the application is running fine. It runs fine for first 15 mins (triggers every unlock event). However, after 15 mins the application just don't work.

The history log of the task shows that the task started and completed successfully without any error. The task manager shows the tasks running too. However the app is not running in full screen mode. it is not visible.

The dev who created the windows form application says there's no error on his side as the application runs every time I manually click on the icon. The problem happens only when it is triggered through task scheduler.

What is happening here? Is there a limit on how many times a full screen app can run through task scheduler or something? We are talking about Windows 10 and above here.

Please help.